# Am I handling users' passwords safely(Django + Gunicorn HTTP vs HTTPS)?

Tags: django, http, https, gunicorn, django-authentication

I have a django website running the django-auth package to let users register and sign in. I haven't changed anything about how django-auth implements register and sign in, so there should be no issues there.

I'm running my server through gunicorn, and after setting up SSL and changing port to 443, I noticed that when you type example.com there's no response because the server isn't running on http anymore, only https.

I searched around for solutions and it said I had to set up nginx or a reverse proxy of some sort, I've decided to skip that step and maybe set it up later. What I did was run two instances of gunicorn, one on port 80 and one on port 443. Then I ran some code to redirect the http traffic to https traffic:

```
   if request.scheme is 'http' and settings.DEBUG is False:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('https://www.example.com')
```

I know this is probably a bad idea, and I should really switch to nginx soon, I'm not concerned with any performance losses yet or any security losses since I don't carry any sensitive data EXCEPT for the users' passwords.

All I want to know is, does just having an http version of the website up pose a security risk to passwords, or is it fine? Could bad actors use the fact that parts of my website are not https to find out my users' passwords?

Comment: If you use a CDN like Cloudflare for routing traffic, they will automatically route all your traffic to https.

Comment: I don't believe I'm using one, all I have is a droplet on DigitalOcean, and gunicorn running within that droplet.